# How can I reverse sudo apt-get install command

Tags: ubuntu

In ubuntu, I did these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential vala-desktop-agnostic checkinstall
sudo apt-get build-dep avant-window-navigator
```

How can i un-apt-get, or uninstall the packages it pulls in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First your remove the packages with remove or purge

```
sudo apt-get purge build-essential vala-desktop-agnostic checkinstall
sudo apt-get purge ....
```

Then you remove now unneeded dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

In the case of build-dep you will have to figure out manually which packages are build-dependencies of avant-window-manager. Synaptic will tell you that.

Answer (score 4):

apt-get remove should do the trick, apt-get purge if you want to dump the config files as well.

Comment: Also, "apt-get autoremove" to remove packages that was installed as a dependency, but uninstalled everything that depends on it.

Comment: apt-get --purge remove packagename

Comment: yeah, but if you apt-get remove it'll tell you about autoremove ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first step will remove the `install`ed packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge build-essential vala-desktop-agnostic checkinstall
```

The second step will search for the `build-dep`s and mark them as automatically installed, and hence removable:

```
sudo aptitude markauto $(apt-cache showsrc PACKAGE_NAME | sed -e '/Build-Depends/!d;s/Build-Depends: \|,\|([^)]*),*\|\[[^]]*\]//g')
```

You may or may not then need the third step:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Ref: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/undo-apt-get-build-dep-remove-build.html